# What is a "crippled serial flirt"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I got this expression from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barchester_Towers) regarding the novel "Barchester Towers" by Anthony Trollope.

The full sentence is:

> Signora Madeline Vesey Neroni is a crippled serial flirt with a young daughter and a mysterious Italian husband whom she has left.

I cannot make much sense of this phrase, can you help?

Comment: [crippled](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crippled?q=crippled), [serial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serial#serial__5), [flirt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flirt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary will show you the meanings of all these words. *Crippled* means disabled, but it is not much used now. A *flirt* is a man or woman who pretends to have a sexual or romantic interest in another, but without serious intentions. A *serial flirt* is someone who behaves in such a way with one person after another.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, in some contexts, _crippled_ could be used as an adjective to describe the subject's ability to flirt, as opposed to a physical disability. For example: _He was a serial flirt, but now he's crippled by his gray hair and aging frame._ That would mean he can't flirt like he used to.